# Fatal error when calling drupal_goto from hook_boot

Tags: 7, hooks, redirection

When I am trying to call drupal_goto from hook_boot I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function drupal_goto()

What am I doing wrong and why is that happening?

My code:

```
function custom_mobile_redirect_boot() {
  include_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
  $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
  if ($detect->isMobile() || $detect->isTablet()) {
    drupal_goto('http://testsite.local');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `hook_boot()` lot of APIs will not work as the required function definitions for them will not be loaded. In this case `common.inc` where `drupal_goto()` is defined is not yet included ergo you get that error. If its not possible to use hook_init() make use of [Header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). Check out [mobile_tools module](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools/) hook_boot() for more info.